# Report designer and viewer of custom data in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, report

I've custom data list, for example list of persons:
-name 
-surname
-photo

I'd like to give my customers opprtunity to design, how would they like to see this data in exported document:

```
name | surname | photo
```

or

```
name surname
photo
```

etc.

Do you know any easy to use tools that could help? It would be wonderful if they would be free :).

Answer (score 1):

You Can do this using Visual Studio Report Viewer. And its free(aslong as you have visual Studio)

Its similar to access Reports so its interface is pretty simple to use.

If your data is in a table then all you need to do is follow the wizard for a table on the report and hey presto your sorted!

If like me you love to be different and annoying, and have your data in your form then follow my post when i had the problems.

[Report viewer set Parameters iList parameters error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415933/report-viewer-set-parameters-ilist-parameters-error)

or

[report viewer pass image from form possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396798/report-viewer-pass-image-from-form-possible)

Hope this helps!

The GUI side could be a form, the user has some constraits that edit the position size etc. I think then its possible to pass these through to Paramters in the report that have expressions that effect the report controls.  But I'm not 100% on that hopefully someone else has a better answer!

Comment: Thanks, old question but still... Customer does not have VS.

Comment: if the product is coded in visual studio IDE then on publish the reports a dn its viewer are all configured on your program, simply like a control.  Or am I not getting it?

Comment: and wow yeh is old question but seemed perfect for me to answer since i was dealing with a very similar problem at the time hehe

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress has XtraReports which has a end user report designer.

[XtraReports End User Designer](http://www1.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/user-designer.xml)

It's well worth the cost, all of our customers love it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd say it's rather expensive. And isn't its too complicated for a simple data input?

Comment: Well the reporting part is only $350, I however do not know your budget. What kind of design do you mean then if you are not wanting a graphical rep.