# Report viewer set Parameters iList parameters error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, return, reportviewer, ilist

Morning all,

Using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and C#.NET 4.0.

```
IList<Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter> param = new List<Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter>();

param = repsetup.NewReportSetup(
    txtNewPart.Text.ToString(),
    txtBatch.Text.ToString(), 
    txtLocation.Text.ToString(), 
    txtWheel.Text.ToString(), 
    txtGear.Text.ToString(), 
    txtLength.Text.ToString(),
    txtFits.Text.ToString(), 
    txtNewBar.Text.ToString(), 
    txtNewBarNum.Text.ToString(), 
    txtABS.Text.ToString()
);

reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter(param));
```

When trying to set the report parameters it complains about the list.
The list is populated in another table and returns a list.

```
Error 2 - Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter>' to 'string'
```

Also error:

```
Error 1 - The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter.ReportParameter(string)' has some invalid arguments
```

How do I use the `IList` in the `SetParameters` method?

Many Thanks

Here's the `NewReportSetup` method:

```
public IList<Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter> NewReportSetup(string part, string batch, string locn, string wheel, string gear, string length,
                                string fits, string newbar, string newbarnum, string abs)
{
    IList<Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter> parameters = new List<Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter>();
    parameters.Add( new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramPart", part));
    parameters.Add( new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramBatch", batch));
    parameters.Add( new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramLocn", locn));
    parameters.Add( new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramWheel", wheel));
    parameters.Add( new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramGear", gear));
    parameters.Add( new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramLength", length));
    parameters.Add( new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramABS", abs));
    parameters.Add( new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramBuyer", fits));
    parameters.Add( new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramBarCode", newbar));
    parameters.Add( new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramBartxt", newbarnum));
    return parameters;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Report.SetParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252195%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method requires an `IEnumerable<ReportParameter>`:

In other words send your list of report parameters to this method, not an instance of a `ReportParameter` (which you're trying to create from your list):

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(param);
```

Comment: many thanks for the reply, not entirly sure What you mean though, You a got a quick Snippet i could look at?

Comment: The snippet is reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(param); Change your last line to that.